# Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition

Tags: dell, firmware

Are there any hardware differences between the Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition and a regular Dell XPS 13?  Can one simply buy the regular one and install their updated firmware and Ubuntu distribution?  It's seemingly not possible to get 16 gigs of RAM in the developer edition.

Comment: Hardware is off topic in askubuntu.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pure hardware question... (Sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly the same hardware. You easily can install Ubuntu on it.

Ubuntu 15.10 comes with a lot of fixes (and kernel 4.2) and will work even better than Ubuntu 14.04.

If you are interested - I have written a [full step-by-step guide](http://hgdev.co/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-the-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide-update/) on how to install Ubuntu 15.10 on this laptop and get everything working properly.

Comment: Caution: The accepted answer is wrong. The hardware is quite different. The regular XPS 13 is Skylake based and has modern interfaces like USB-C, sadly the developer edition is still Broadwell based.

Comment: What kind of "a lot of fixes"are you always talking about? I see a lot of bugs. 15.10 is not recommended for newbies.

Comment: @Andreas  I am talking about the current Dell XPS 13 generation (2015 edition 9343).

Comment: Appears the 9343 is no longer the current Dell XPS 13 generation.  And maybe the 9343 never had a 16gb configuration.  I'm quite happy merely to know that they were the same configuration at some point however.

Comment: I compared them when I was purchasing my XPS in August 2015 and they had the same hardware (that is, there was one Windows model that was identical to the Linux one: the range for windows is much more broad). If you compare them across the same generation, then they should be identical.

Comment: Also, no problems here at all on 15.10. Running smoothly and enjoying it.
... and I can't say the same about Windows 10, which has a tremendous bug on the Wireless drivers, which will drop connection every 30 seconds or so!!!